# Set an image in the DOM and change it

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener, event-listener

this is probably really simple, but I just can not get it to work.

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game with html, Javascript and CSS.

my js is connected to my html just fine, I am attmepting to add some event listeners on my board so that when a player clicks the square they are clicking goes from blank to a cross.

I have a cross image saved at "images/cross.png"

the html of my table looks like this:

```
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="1"></td>
        <td id="2"></td>
        <td id="3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="4"></td>
        <td id="5"></td>
        <td id="6"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="7"></td>
        <td id="8"></td>
        <td id="9"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

My logic is as follows:

- run a for loop and create an empty image element in each td element of the board:
- add an event listener to each td element also
- When this td element is clicked set the src of the image to the image located at images/cross.png

here is the code to start the board:

```
for (let x = 1; x <= 9; x++){
    let cross = document.createElement("img");
    cross.addEventListener("click", click);
    document.getElementById(x).appendChild(cross);
  }
};
```

and then my event listener function is:

```
function click() {
  console.log("this is working")
  this.setAttribute("src","images/cross.png")
};
```

and I obviously run my initial function to initialize the js:

```
testMarker();
```

my board is unresponsive after this.

Comment: An image without a `src` and without dimensions is 0x0 pixels. You can't click it. Edit: it works if you set dimensions, for instance with CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/opusy19b/

Comment: no, the browser does not lock up. This is all the code I have, so it must be enough!

Comment: thanks @ChrisG, that was the solution!